# How to record audio to AAC format in android using MediaRecorder?

Tags: android, audio, microphone, mediarecorder, aac

I've tried everything, but can't seem to get `MediaRecorder` to record audio from microphone to `.aac` format. I have tried playing with `OutputFormat`/`AudioEncoder`, but nothing works. Here is my code:

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AAC_ADTS);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
recorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/recordings/test.aac");
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
```

As the program records, the audio file does grow, but after I stop recording with:

```
recorder.stop();
recorder.release();
```

The file is corrupt and does not play. What am I doing wrong and how can I record sound to proper AAC format?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't play?  Did you expect it to immediately play when you stop recording?  It doesn't do that.  If you used some other code to play it, post that as well.

Comment: @GabeSechan Sorry for the confusion. The file is corrupt, and when I try to play it with an audio player app, it does not work.